# Storing and accessing data in a py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, shelve

I want to automate the downloading of torrents each week.
Specifically, I want to store in a dictionary the name of the series, the season, and the episode, something along:

```
series = {'Last.Week.Tonight':{'S':05,'E':14},'Ducktales':{'S':01,'E':10}}
```

The program then uses the dictionary to download the latest episode from a torrent site, very simple.

My problem is that I would like to store the variable in another .py file and then import it.
This is because:

1. I want to create the variable by webscraping a website I use to be updated with tv series, so that if I add a new series to the website the program can add the corresponding key in the dictionary
2. I want to update the variable independently from the main program that downloads episodes
3. I want other programs to access it

Moreover, after having downloaded the episode I want my main program to update series(i.e. augmenting the episode of 1, or, if the result for the episode is nonexistent, update the season by 1).
Can I write a script that changes variable in another script?

I know that the shelve module exists, but I am still a beginner, and the advantage to have a .py file would be that I could see more easily the data my program is working on.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you consider storing the info in some other file (i.e. csv)?

Comment: Storing your data as Python source will work okay will if you set it up in a text editor, save it, then import it. Your problem is going to come with updating existing data. What you then want is to have update program import a Python module, update the data in it and write out modified source. It's possible but it is a difficult approach, and much harder than converting your data for storage in a more conventional file structure.

Comment: The .csv could solve all my problems, because I could read it in a text editor and update what I need from different scripts. Does it support dictionary, or should I use another way to store info? I have yet to work with .csv

Answer (score 1):

store your data as either [json](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html)